Configuring Python Linters to ignore specific errors (not error types) without using annotations in source code
Is it possible to configure linters in Visual Studio Code, like mypy or pylint, to ignore very specific error cases without making annotations in the source code?
For example
MeVisLab requires the wildcard import from mevis import * to make the variable ctx accessible in code. I can't do from mevis import ctx because ctx is not defined in the package; yet somehow when I do the star import, it works as required.
Many linters not only flag the wildcard import but also throw the error that ctx is undefined.
I would like to configure the linters so that all appearances of ctx.<some expression>
and the specific wildcard imports from mevis import * are ignored.
At the same time I want to still see errors for all other undefined variables and wildcard imports.

I know about the possibility to disable the linters for certain lines
with annotations like # type : ignore. But I am looking
specifically for solutions that do not require any changes of the
source code.
I also have tried to use configuration files but as far
as I saw those only allow to deactive certain error types like
undefined variable instead of ignore all appearance of the ctx variable.
I also tried using the scope functionality of sonarcube
but it is not blocking the lines with ctx correctly.

If I would use the # type : ignore syntax in every line ctx appears, I would have to annotate almost every second line in my code, which is not only work intensive but also, for me, makes the code more difficult to read. If I instead exclude the whole module / file or disable the error message I would then also hide actual errors which would take away the benefit of the linter. As such the typical options both have significant disadvantage in my specific use case.

@tripleee I am aware that this would be the correct way in python to manage the import. Sadly MeVisLab does not accept this kind of import and throws the following error.
ImportError: cannot import name 'ctx' from 'mevis' (unknown location)
The variable is found without problem if the star import is used.

I'm not familiar with that package but my impulse would be to report that as a bug.

@tripleee MeVisLab is not a package but like a separate programming language / IDE that has the build in functionality to inferace with python scripts. I am unsure if the interface can be handled differently.

Thanks for engaging with me and for useful clarifications. Going forward, probably [edit] your question in response to comments rather than replying with another comment if the information you provide isn't already clearly included in the question.

you can modify the configuration of pylint in the config file. In .pylintrc, it can be closed using the warning code specified by disable=. Or try to solve it by ignore a specific module by extend-ignore=.

Thank you for your answer but I do not think that this solves my issue. As I understand it, your solution would completely disable for example the warning undefined variable so that not only ctx but every undefined variable would be ignored and not shown as an error. I specifically want to ignore only the error concerning the ctx variable, so that the error messages in IDE or reports in CI/CD setup are not spammed with these unavoidable error.  At the same time all other undefined variables should still be highlighted as an error.

Hi, now linters doesn't provide a way to close very specific bugs directly. This method is trouble, the best thing to do at the moment is to disable wildcard imports and undefined variable warnings globally, and then manually check for problem in your code.

For the record, the downvote is from me, not from the OP. In my opinion, the question already specified clearly that this type of solution is not what the OP is looking for.
